# LaTeX incorrect figure numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, subfloats

I have several figures and subfigures in a LaTeX file, but only the first few are numbered correctly. Here is the part of the code that is giving me problems:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}         

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=5in]{figure1.png}
  \caption{Caption1}
\label{fig:fig1} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp!]
 \caption{caption2}   \label{fig:fig2}
        \centering        
 \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{subfig1.png}
                \caption{subfig1}
                \label{fig:subfig1}
        \end{subfigure}

          \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{subfig2.png}
                \caption{subfig2}
                \label{fig:subfig2}
        \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}

 \newpage
\begin{figure}[htp!]
\centering
\ContinuedFloat
          \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{subfig3.png}
                \caption{subfig3}
                \label{fig:subfig3}
        \end{subfigure}


          \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{subfig4.png}
                \caption{subfig4}
                \label{fig:subfig4}
        \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}

 \newpage
\begin{figure}[htp!]
\centering 
  \includegraphics[width=5in]{figure3.png}
  \caption{Caption3}
\label{fig:fig3} 

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Fig.1 and Fig.2 are correctly numbered, but Fig.3 is numbered Fig.1. The subplots in Fig.2 are also numbered incorrectly: the first four are labeled (a)-(d), but the fifth on the third page starts from (a) again. Does `\ContinuedFloat` not work over more than two pages?

Here is the output of `\listfiles`:

```
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
subcaption.sty    2012/01/12 v1.1d Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2012/02/19 v3.2f Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2012/01/12 v1.4b caption3 kernel (AR)
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
supp-pdf.mkii
  omscmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
```

Comment: On my system (TeX Live2013) the numbering is OK. What LaTeX system do you use?

Comment: I think it's MiKTeX 2.9?

Comment: In miktex 2.9, it works OK here. May be you need to update packages.

Comment: Can you pleas add `\listfiles` to the preamble of the *exact* code you just posted; compile it, then open the `.log` file, search the `*File List*` section and add the content of that list to your question?

Comment: Compare yours with the versions of some relevant files in my system: `subcaption.sty    2013/02/03 v1.1-62 Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)`. This strongly suggests that updating your package(s) (perhaps even your complete LaTeX system) is the way to go here.

Comment: Older versions of the `(sub)caption` package used to show problems if the position (top or bottom) of the caption will be changed within the document, i.e. is inconsistent, and that's what you are doing here: The 1st figure have its caption below the figure content, the 2nd above (but with sub-captions below), and the 3rd one have it again below the figure content. So either decide for one - above or below the content - or update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Yes, updating `caption` solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue fixed in the latest release of the relevant packages.